# SSL peer shut down incorrectly at org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat, file-upload

I get below exception while uploading the files on server.

Server is Tomcat 7 and I am using spring-mvc + apache file upload .

My website runs on https.
Why the error is coming "SSL peer shut down incorrectly"?

```
     : Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is 
org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of 
multipart/form-data request failed. SSL peer shut down incorrectly 
org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse multipart servlet 
request; nested exception is 
org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of 
multipart/form-data request failed. SSL peer shut down incorrectly at 
org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver.parseRequest(CommonsMultipartResolver.java:163) at 
org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver.resolveMultipart(CommonsMultipartResolver.java:139) at 
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.checkMultipart(DispatcherServlet.java:1047) at 
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:892) at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856) at 
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936) at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647) at 
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728) at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305) at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) at 
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) at 
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118) at 
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84) at 
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160) at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123) at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:581) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171) at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99) at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408) at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1008) at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) Caused by: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. SSL peer shut down incorrectly at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:351) at org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(ServletFileUpload.java:115) at org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver.parseRequest(CommonsMultipartResolver.java:156) ... 53 more Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.readV3Record(InputRecord.java:537) at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:489) at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:863) at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:820) at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:75) at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.fill(InternalInputBuffer.java:532) at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.fill(InternalInputBuffer.java:501) at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer$InputStreamInputBuffer.doRead(InternalInputBuffer.java:563) at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityInputFilter.doRead(IdentityInputFilter.java:124) at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractInputBuffer.doRead(AbstractInputBuffer.java:346) at org.apache.coyote.Request.doRead(Request.java:422) at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadBytes(InputBuffer.java:290) at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.substract(ByteChunk.java:449) at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:315) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:200) at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.makeAvailable(MultipartStream.java:999) at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.read(MultipartStream.java:903) at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:82) at org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:100) at org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:70) at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:347) ... 55 more
```

Comment: The only thing I could find based on a google search of "SSL peer shut down incorrectly" is that maybe the server has a file/upload size limit.  Do you know if the sever you're uploading files to has a file size limit?

Comment: I am not sure about that, I will check and update. But we have 10MB max size limit for a file (On client side). Unless it is less than 10MB it won't allow to submit the file. I think that is not very high. What do you think?

Comment: It doesn't matter what I think, it matters what the server thinks.  :)